How to make a Node.js Socket.io server accessible via public IP?
I'm running a socket.io server on my Windows machine and want it to be accessible over the internet using its public IP. Here’s what I've done so far:

Port Forwarding: Successfully opened and forwarded port 5000 to my Windows machine.

Firewall: Allowed inbound traffic on port 5000 (TCP) for all networks (Public, Private, Domain).

Testing Locally: Works when the client connects via the local IP (http://10.0.0.127:5000).

Also, checked on https://portchecker.co/ that port (5000) is open.


The server is not accessible when using my public IP, despite these configurations. How can I properly configure my socket.io remote server to be accessible over a public IP?


//server.js

const { createServer } = require('http');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');

const httpServer = createServer();

const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"]
  }
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('User connected:', socket.id);
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
httpServer.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Socket.io server running on port ${port}`);
});




don't forget you need the OUTBOUND port open also.  Tip, open EVERYTHIGN ion both directions while you try to get it working.

@Fattie Done but same "pending" and after some time Connection timed out. Thanks for pointing that out.

It's a nightmare getting these working.  My code usually looks something like ..
const https = require("https")
const WebSocket = require('ws')

and then ..
// have to fire up a https (that's "s") >>specifically for<< your wss
let for_2666 = https.createServer(main.certs).listen(2666, (err) => {
    if (err) { return console.log('2828 woe', err) }
})

// and then ..
let WSServer = WebSocket.Server
let wss = new WSServer({
    server: for_2666,
    perMessageDeflate: false
})

console.log("mp rt server 2666 AOK")

and ..
wss.on('connection', function connection(u) {

    // Any and all messages arrive:
    u.on('message', function incoming(m) {
        .. handle incoming commands from this connection
    })

    u.on('close', async function incoming(codeNumber, codeReason) {
        .. handle close from this connection
    })

    // possibly send welcome message etc
})

const interval = setInterval(function ping() {
    .. send pings (a whole artform)
}, pingBasis)

wss.on('close', function close() { // SERVER close!! not a connection close!!
    .. handle somewhow
})

Hope it helps

Same issue persists. Not able to call via Public IP (

Gotchya, I am sorry to hear it.  My guess is it relates to the DNS setup. That can be so tricky.

Finally I resolved it and it was related to NAT loopback. I was not able to test it properly because of my Verizon phone does not allow me to use hotspot unless I pay for it extra (for different public IP to test locally with http). I got someone's hotspot and it worked. Thanks for help @Fattie
